# HTTP 400 Error when accessing Friends list in Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I access the list of my friends using the URL https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=... I can see the list of my friends. I can do this programmatically as well.

Now, when I take the ID of any of my friends and replace it with "me" in the above URL, and paste the URL in the browser, I can see my friend's friends. I am unable to do this programmatically because it is giving me an HTTP 400 ERROR.

Does anyone know why this is possible by pasting the URL and not programmatically?

Comment: what is the exact error message in the response?

Comment: I cannot see the response but it is giving me a java.IO Exception. I am using the following code to read the URL:                               ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        con.setConnectTimeout(20000);
        con.setReadTimeout(20000);
        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
        int r;
        while ((r = is.read()) != -1) {
            baos.write(r);
        }
        return new String(baos.toByteArray());

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same id when you use the browser and when you try it programmatically? Can you show me some code you are using the make the request?

Comment: Yes, I am using the same ID. Here is the code:                                                                  friendID2 = "503353623";
                
                try {
                    url = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/"+friendID2+"/friends?access_token=" + accessToken);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                }
                try {
                    result = ReadMyURL.readURL(url);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }

Comment: Is the user you're trying to get the friends for, that is USER_ID/friends, a user of your app?

Comment: No, he is not the user of my app. USER_ID is just my friend. I am trying to get the list of friends of USER_ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not get the "friends of friends" using the facebook api.

For example, try the simple [/me/friends](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/friends) with the Graph API Explorer, it should work fine.
Then, take one of the ids there and try the same with FRIEND_ID/friends and you should get this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#604) Can't lookup all friends of FRIEN_ID. Can only lookup for the logged in user or the logged in user's friends that are users of your app.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 604
  }
}
```

The error itself is very straight forward and explains exactly what the problem is.
As for why that translates into a 400 error code for you is unclear.

---

## Edit

You can't see the "friends of friends" in the browser as well, the reason that it works for you (probably) is that the user(s) you check the friends for (USER_ID/friends) installed the app that the access token belongs to, from the way you got to that url I assume that the app is the "Test_console".

How to check? Copy the access token from the url (USER_ID/friends?access_token=xxxxx), go to the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and paste the token in the text field and click "Debug", it will show you info regarding the application.

The user you checked it for probably has that app "installed", if you check it for other users you will get that error when you get to a user who does not have that app "installed".

I hope this clarifies it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I got friends of friends(limited) who are using application. I had same problem. Though it is very late for answering question, it will help somebody. That's why answering this question.

We can get friends of friends those are app users.

$fb_id= user id whose friends of friends required.

Try this fql query.

> $query="SELECT uid, name, work_history  FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT
>   uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 IN (SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN
>   (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = $fb_id ) and is_app_user=1) )";

It needs following requirements:

1. Your friend needs to be using application.
2. Permission from application read_stream, publish_stream, publish_checkins.